# FFT image/pixelcolors with fftw library

Tags: image-processing, fft, fftw

I am trying to forward Fast Fourier Transfer an Image and then backward Fast Fourier Transfer it. I am using the library from http://www.fftw.org/. The thing is that I have stored the RGB values in a one dimensional array in the listed order. The way I think would work is to allocate arrays for each of the colors and do a separate FFT for each array. Like this:

```
fftw_plan_dft_2d(imageWidth, imageHeight, pixelColor, fft_result, FFTW_FORWARD,
FFTW_ESTIMATE)
```

I don't know much about FFT but to me it doesn't seem like an ideal way to do it. Can someone tell me if there is a better way to FFT all the pixelcolors from an Image with the library from fftw.org?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No sure what an fft of a colour image would mean.
Presumably you want to look at structure in each colour or more common - just make a greyscale (intensity) image and work on that

Comment: I want to do a Gaussian blur in the frequency domain. I assume that can't be done correctly on a grayscale image? After the backward FFT I need to restore the image colors.

Comment: If you do a blur in each colour separately you will introduce colour fringes. I would convert to HSV, blur the intensity channel and then convert back to RGB